# How to fill in cells with data from two separate cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a big Google Sheet and I need to do something like this:

x A x B x C
A AA BA CA
B AB BB CB
C AC BC CC
What formula would allow me to copy the info from the above and right cells into one cell?

(Sorry for the x’s couldn’t figure out how to get a double space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(B1:D1&A2:A4)
```

in B2 gives this:
[image: test]

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.